# Scale filter crashes with error when used from transcoding example

Tags: c++, filter, ffmpeg, scale, stride

I've modified a bit (just to compile in c++) this code example: 
https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/transcoding.c.

What works: as is (null filter), a number of other filters like framerate, drawtext, ...

What doesn't work: **scale filter** when scaling down.

I use the following syntax for scale ( I've tried many others also, same effect):
    "scale=w=iw/2:-1"

**The error is**: "Input picture width (240) is greater than stride (128)" where the values for width and stride depend on the input.

Misc environment info: windows, VS 2017, input example: rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov

Any clue as to what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks !

---

EDITED to add working code sample

---

```
#pragma comment(lib, "avcodec.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "avutil.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "avformat.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "avfilter.lib")

/*
* Copyright (c) 2010 Nicolas George
* Copyright (c) 2011 Stefano Sabatini
* Copyright (c) 2014 Andrey Utkin
*
**** EDITED 2017 for testing (see original here: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/transcoding.c)
*
* Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
* of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
* in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
* to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
* copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
* furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
*
* The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
* all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
*
* THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
* IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
* FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL
* THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
* LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
* OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
* THE SOFTWARE.
*/

/**
* @file
* API example for demuxing, decoding, filtering, encoding and muxing
* @example transcoding.c
*/

extern "C"
{
    #include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
    #include <libavformat/avformat.h>
    #include <libavfilter/avfiltergraph.h>
    #include <libavfilter/buffersink.h>
    #include <libavfilter/buffersrc.h>
    #include <libavutil/opt.h>
    #include <libavutil/pixdesc.h>
}


static AVFormatContext *ifmt_ctx;
static AVFormatContext *ofmt_ctx;
typedef struct FilteringContext {
    AVFilterContext *buffersink_ctx;
    AVFilterContext *buffersrc_ctx;
    AVFilterGraph *filter_graph;
} FilteringContext;
static FilteringContext *filter_ctx;

typedef struct StreamContext {
    AVCodecContext *dec_ctx;
    AVCodecContext *enc_ctx;
} StreamContext;
static StreamContext *stream_ctx;

static int open_input_file(const char *filename, int& videoStreamIndex)
{
    int ret;
    unsigned int i;

    ifmt_ctx = NULL;
    if ((ret = avformat_open_input(&ifmt_ctx, filename, NULL, NULL)) < 0) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot open input file\n");
        return ret;
    }

    if ((ret = avformat_find_stream_info(ifmt_ctx, NULL)) < 0) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot find stream information\n");
        return ret;
    }

    // Just need video
    videoStreamIndex = -1;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ifmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++)
    {
        if (ifmt_ctx->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type != AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
            continue;
        videoStreamIndex = i;
        break;
    }
    if (videoStreamIndex < 0)
    {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot find video stream\n");
        return videoStreamIndex;
    }


    stream_ctx = (StreamContext*)av_mallocz_array(ifmt_ctx->nb_streams, sizeof(*stream_ctx));
    if (!stream_ctx)
        return AVERROR(ENOMEM);

    for (i = 0; i < ifmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++) {

        // Just need video
        if (i != videoStreamIndex)
            continue;


        AVStream *stream = ifmt_ctx->streams[i];
        AVCodec *dec = avcodec_find_decoder(stream->codecpar->codec_id);
        AVCodecContext *codec_ctx;
        if (!dec) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Failed to find decoder for stream #%u\n", i);
            return AVERROR_DECODER_NOT_FOUND;
        }
        codec_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(dec);
        if (!codec_ctx) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Failed to allocate the decoder context for stream #%u\n", i);
            return AVERROR(ENOMEM);
        }
        ret = avcodec_parameters_to_context(codec_ctx, stream->codecpar);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Failed to copy decoder parameters to input decoder context "
                "for stream #%u\n", i);
            return ret;
        }
        /* Reencode video & audio and remux subtitles etc. */
        if (codec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO
            || codec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
            if (codec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
                codec_ctx->framerate = av_guess_frame_rate(ifmt_ctx, stream, NULL);
            /* Open decoder */
            ret = avcodec_open2(codec_ctx, dec, NULL);
            if (ret < 0) {
                av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Failed to open decoder for stream #%u\n", i);
                return ret;
            }
        }
        stream_ctx[i].dec_ctx = codec_ctx;
    }

    av_dump_format(ifmt_ctx, 0, filename, 0);
    return 0;
}

static int open_output_file(const char *filename, const int videoStreamIndex)
{
    AVStream *out_stream;
    AVStream *in_stream;
    AVCodecContext *dec_ctx, *enc_ctx;
    AVCodec *encoder;
    int ret;
    unsigned int i;

    ofmt_ctx = NULL;
    avformat_alloc_output_context2(&ofmt_ctx, NULL, NULL, filename);
    if (!ofmt_ctx) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Could not create output context\n");
        return AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
    }


    for (i = 0; i < ifmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++) {
        // Just need video
        if (i != videoStreamIndex)
            continue;

        out_stream = avformat_new_stream(ofmt_ctx, NULL);
        if (!out_stream) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Failed allocating output stream\n");
            return AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
        }

        in_stream = ifmt_ctx->streams[i];
        dec_ctx = stream_ctx[i].dec_ctx;

        if (dec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            /* in this example, we choose transcoding to same codec */
            encoder = avcodec_find_encoder(dec_ctx->codec_id);
            if (!encoder) {
                av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_FATAL, "Necessary encoder not found\n");
                return AVERROR_INVALIDDATA;
            }
            enc_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(encoder);
            if (!enc_ctx) {
                av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_FATAL, "Failed to allocate the encoder context\n");
                return AVERROR(ENOMEM);
            }

            /* In this example, we transcode to same properties (picture size,
            * sample rate etc.). These properties can be changed for output
            * streams easily using filters */
            enc_ctx->height = dec_ctx->height;
            enc_ctx->width = dec_ctx->width;
            enc_ctx->sample_aspect_ratio = dec_ctx->sample_aspect_ratio;
            /* take first format from list of supported formats */
            if (encoder->pix_fmts)
                enc_ctx->pix_fmt = encoder->pix_fmts[0];
            else
                enc_ctx->pix_fmt = dec_ctx->pix_fmt;

            /* video time_base can be set to whatever is handy and supported by encoder */
            //enc_ctx->time_base = av_inv_q(dec_ctx->framerate);
            enc_ctx->time_base = dec_ctx->time_base;


            /* Third parameter can be used to pass settings to encoder */
            ret = avcodec_open2(enc_ctx, encoder, NULL);
            if (ret < 0) {
                av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot open video encoder for stream #%u\n", i);
                return ret;
            }
            ret = avcodec_parameters_from_context(out_stream->codecpar, enc_ctx);
            if (ret < 0) {
                av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Failed to copy encoder parameters to output stream #%u\n", i);
                return ret;
            }
            if (ofmt_ctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
                enc_ctx->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;

            out_stream->time_base = enc_ctx->time_base;
            stream_ctx[i].enc_ctx = enc_ctx;
        }
        else if (dec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_UNKNOWN) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_FATAL, "Elementary stream #%d is of unknown type, cannot proceed\n", i);
            return AVERROR_INVALIDDATA;
        }
        else {
            /* if this stream must be remuxed */
            ret = avcodec_parameters_copy(out_stream->codecpar, in_stream->codecpar);
            if (ret < 0) {
                av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Copying parameters for stream #%u failed\n", i);
                return ret;
            }
            out_stream->time_base = in_stream->time_base;
        }

    }
    av_dump_format(ofmt_ctx, 0, filename, 1);

    if (!(ofmt_ctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
        ret = avio_open(&ofmt_ctx->pb, filename, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Could not open output file '%s'", filename);
            return ret;
        }
    }

    /* init muxer, write output file header */
    ret = avformat_write_header(ofmt_ctx, NULL);
    if (ret < 0) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Error occurred when opening output file\n");
        return ret;
    }

    return 0;
}

static int init_filter(FilteringContext* fctx, AVCodecContext *dec_ctx,
    AVCodecContext *enc_ctx, const char *filter_spec)
{
    char args[512];
    int ret = 0;
    AVFilter *buffersrc = NULL;
    AVFilter *buffersink = NULL;
    AVFilterContext *buffersrc_ctx = NULL;
    AVFilterContext *buffersink_ctx = NULL;
    AVFilterInOut *outputs = avfilter_inout_alloc();
    AVFilterInOut *inputs = avfilter_inout_alloc();
    AVFilterGraph *filter_graph = avfilter_graph_alloc();

    if (!outputs || !inputs || !filter_graph) {
        ret = AVERROR(ENOMEM);
        goto end;
    }

    if (dec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
        buffersrc = avfilter_get_by_name("buffer");
        buffersink = avfilter_get_by_name("buffersink");
        if (!buffersrc || !buffersink) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "filtering source or sink element not found\n");
            ret = AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
            goto end;
        }

        snprintf(args, sizeof(args),
            "video_size=%dx%d:pix_fmt=%d:time_base=%d/%d:pixel_aspect=%d/%d",
            dec_ctx->width, dec_ctx->height, dec_ctx->pix_fmt,
            dec_ctx->time_base.num, dec_ctx->time_base.den,
            dec_ctx->sample_aspect_ratio.num,
            dec_ctx->sample_aspect_ratio.den);

        ret = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&buffersrc_ctx, buffersrc, "in",
            args, NULL, filter_graph);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot create buffer source\n");
            goto end;
        }

        ret = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&buffersink_ctx, buffersink, "out",
            NULL, NULL, filter_graph);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot create buffer sink\n");
            goto end;
        }

        ret = av_opt_set_bin(buffersink_ctx, "pix_fmts",
            (uint8_t*)&enc_ctx->pix_fmt, sizeof(enc_ctx->pix_fmt),
            AV_OPT_SEARCH_CHILDREN);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot set output pixel format\n");
            goto end;
        }
    }
    else {
        ret = AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
        goto end;
    }

    /* Endpoints for the filter graph. */
    outputs->name = av_strdup("in");
    outputs->filter_ctx = buffersrc_ctx;
    outputs->pad_idx = 0;
    outputs->next = NULL;

    inputs->name = av_strdup("out");
    inputs->filter_ctx = buffersink_ctx;
    inputs->pad_idx = 0;
    inputs->next = NULL;

    if (!outputs->name || !inputs->name) {
        ret = AVERROR(ENOMEM);
        goto end;
    }

    if ((ret = avfilter_graph_parse_ptr(filter_graph, filter_spec,
        &inputs, &outputs, NULL)) < 0)
        goto end;

    if ((ret = avfilter_graph_config(filter_graph, NULL)) < 0)
        goto end;

    /* Fill FilteringContext */
    fctx->buffersrc_ctx = buffersrc_ctx;
    fctx->buffersink_ctx = buffersink_ctx;
    fctx->filter_graph = filter_graph;

end:
    avfilter_inout_free(&inputs);
    avfilter_inout_free(&outputs);

    return ret;
}

static int init_filters(const int videoStreamIndex)
{
    const char *filter_spec;
    unsigned int i;
    int ret;
    filter_ctx = (FilteringContext*)av_malloc_array(ifmt_ctx->nb_streams, sizeof(*filter_ctx));
    if (!filter_ctx)
        return AVERROR(ENOMEM);

    for (i = 0; i < ifmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++) {

        // Just video
        if (i != videoStreamIndex)
            continue;

        filter_ctx[i].buffersrc_ctx = NULL;
        filter_ctx[i].buffersink_ctx = NULL;
        filter_ctx[i].filter_graph = NULL;
        if (!(ifmt_ctx->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO
            || ifmt_ctx->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO))
            continue;

        filter_spec = "null"; /* passthrough (dummy) filter for video */
        //filter_spec = "scale=w=iw/2:-1";
        // filter_spec = "drawtext=fontfile=FreeSerif.ttf: text='%{localtime}': x=w-text_w: y=0: fontsize=24: fontcolor=yellow@1.0: box=1: boxcolor=red@1.0";
        // filter_spec = "drawtext=fontfile=FreeSerif.ttf :text='test': x=w-text_w: y=text_h: fontsize=24: fontcolor=yellow@1.0: box=1: boxcolor=red@1.0";

        ret = init_filter(&filter_ctx[i], stream_ctx[i].dec_ctx,
            stream_ctx[i].enc_ctx, filter_spec);
        if (ret)
            return ret;
    }
    return 0;
}

static int encode_write_frame(AVFrame *filt_frame, unsigned int stream_index, int *got_frame, const int videoStreamIndex) {

    // Just video
    if (stream_index != videoStreamIndex)
        return 0;

    int ret;
    int got_frame_local;
    AVPacket enc_pkt;
    int(*enc_func)(AVCodecContext *, AVPacket *, const AVFrame *, int *) =
        (ifmt_ctx->streams[stream_index]->codecpar->codec_type ==
            AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) ? avcodec_encode_video2 : avcodec_encode_audio2;

    if (!got_frame)
        got_frame = &got_frame_local;

    // av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_INFO, "Encoding frame\n");
    /* encode filtered frame */
    enc_pkt.data = NULL;
    enc_pkt.size = 0;
    av_init_packet(&enc_pkt);

    ret = enc_func(stream_ctx[stream_index].enc_ctx, &enc_pkt,
        filt_frame, got_frame);

    av_frame_free(&filt_frame);
    if (ret < 0)
        return ret;
    if (!(*got_frame))
        return 0;

    /* prepare packet for muxing */
    /*enc_pkt.stream_index = stream_index;
    av_packet_rescale_ts(&enc_pkt, stream_ctx[stream_index].enc_ctx->time_base, ofmt_ctx->streams[stream_index]->time_base);*/
    enc_pkt.stream_index = 0;
    av_packet_rescale_ts(&enc_pkt, stream_ctx[stream_index].enc_ctx->time_base, ofmt_ctx->streams[0]->time_base);

    av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_DEBUG, "Muxing frame\n");
    /* mux encoded frame */
    ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(ofmt_ctx, &enc_pkt);
    return ret;
}

static int filter_encode_write_frame(AVFrame *frame, unsigned int stream_index, const int videoStreamIndex)
{
    // Just video, all else crashes
    if (stream_index != videoStreamIndex)
        return 0;

    int ret;
    AVFrame *filt_frame;

    // av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_INFO, "Pushing decoded frame to filters\n");
    /* push the decoded frame into the filtergraph */
    ret = av_buffersrc_add_frame_flags(filter_ctx[stream_index].buffersrc_ctx,
        frame, 0);
    if (ret < 0) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Error while feeding the filtergraph\n");
        return ret;
    }

    /* pull filtered frames from the filtergraph */
    while (1) {
        filt_frame = av_frame_alloc();
        if (!filt_frame) {
            ret = AVERROR(ENOMEM);
            break;
        }
        // av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_INFO, "Pulling filtered frame from filters\n");
        ret = av_buffersink_get_frame(filter_ctx[stream_index].buffersink_ctx,
            filt_frame);
        if (ret < 0) {
            /* if no more frames for output - returns AVERROR(EAGAIN)
            * if flushed and no more frames for output - returns AVERROR_EOF
            * rewrite retcode to 0 to show it as normal procedure completion
            */
            if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF)
                ret = 0;
            av_frame_free(&filt_frame);
            break;
        }

        filt_frame->pict_type = AV_PICTURE_TYPE_NONE;
        ret = encode_write_frame(filt_frame, stream_index, NULL, videoStreamIndex);
        if (ret < 0)
            break;
    }

    return ret;
}

static int flush_encoder(unsigned int stream_index, const int videoStreamIndex)
{
    int ret;
    int got_frame;

    // Just video
    if (stream_index != videoStreamIndex)
        return 0;

    if (!(stream_ctx[stream_index].enc_ctx->codec->capabilities &
        AV_CODEC_CAP_DELAY))
        return 0;

    while (1) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_INFO, "Flushing stream #%u encoder\n", stream_index);
        ret = encode_write_frame(NULL, stream_index, &got_frame, videoStreamIndex);
        if (ret < 0)
            break;
        if (!got_frame)
            return 0;
    }
    return ret;
}


#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int ret;

    AVPacket packet;
    packet.data = NULL;
    packet.size = 0;

    AVFrame *frame = NULL;
    enum AVMediaType type;
    unsigned int stream_index;
    unsigned int i;
    int got_frame;
    int(*dec_func)(AVCodecContext *, AVFrame *, int *, const AVPacket *);


#ifdef _DEBUG
    // Hardcoded arguments
    std::vector<char*> varguments;
    {
        varguments.push_back(argv[0]);

        // Source
        varguments.push_back("./big_buck_bunny_short.mp4 ");

        // Destination
        varguments.push_back("./big_buck_bunny_short-processed.mp4");
    }

    char** arguments = new char*[varguments.size()];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < varguments.size(); i++)
    {
        arguments[i] = varguments[i];
    }
    argc = varguments.size();
    argv = arguments;
#endif // _DEBUG


    if (argc != 3) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Usage: %s <input file> <output file>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    av_register_all();
    avfilter_register_all();

    int videoStreamIndex = -1;
    if ((ret = open_input_file(argv[1], videoStreamIndex)) < 0)
        goto end;
    if ((ret = open_output_file(argv[2], videoStreamIndex)) < 0)
        goto end;
    if ((ret = init_filters(videoStreamIndex)) < 0)
        goto end;

    // Stop after a couple of frames
    int framesToGet = 100;

    /* read all packets */
    //while (framesToGet--)
    while(1)
    {
        if ((ret = av_read_frame(ifmt_ctx, &packet)) < 0)
            break;
        stream_index = packet.stream_index;

        // I just need video
        if (stream_index != videoStreamIndex) {
            av_packet_unref(&packet);
            continue;
        }

        type = ifmt_ctx->streams[packet.stream_index]->codecpar->codec_type;
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_DEBUG, "Demuxer gave frame of stream_index %u\n",
            stream_index);

        if (filter_ctx[stream_index].filter_graph) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_DEBUG, "Going to reencode&filter the frame\n");
            frame = av_frame_alloc();
            if (!frame) {
                ret = AVERROR(ENOMEM);
                break;
            }
            av_packet_rescale_ts(&packet,
                ifmt_ctx->streams[stream_index]->time_base,
                stream_ctx[stream_index].dec_ctx->time_base);
            dec_func = (type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) ? avcodec_decode_video2 :
                avcodec_decode_audio4;
            ret = dec_func(stream_ctx[stream_index].dec_ctx, frame,
                &got_frame, &packet);
            if (ret < 0) {
                av_frame_free(&frame);
                av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Decoding failed\n");
                break;
            }

            if (got_frame) {
                frame->pts = frame->best_effort_timestamp;
                ret = filter_encode_write_frame(frame, stream_index, videoStreamIndex);
                av_frame_free(&frame);
                if (ret < 0)
                    goto end;
            }
            else {
                av_frame_free(&frame);
            }
        }
        else {
            /* remux this frame without reencoding */
            av_packet_rescale_ts(&packet,
                ifmt_ctx->streams[stream_index]->time_base,
                ofmt_ctx->streams[stream_index]->time_base);

            ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(ofmt_ctx, &packet);
            if (ret < 0)
                goto end;
        }
        av_packet_unref(&packet);
    }

    /* flush filters and encoders */
    for (i = 0; i < ifmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++) {
        /* flush filter */
        if (!filter_ctx[i].filter_graph)
            continue;
        ret = filter_encode_write_frame(NULL, i, videoStreamIndex);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Flushing filter failed\n");
            goto end;
        }

        /* flush encoder */
        ret = flush_encoder(i, videoStreamIndex);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Flushing encoder failed\n");
            goto end;
        }
    }

    av_write_trailer(ofmt_ctx);
end:
    av_packet_unref(&packet);
    av_frame_free(&frame);
    for (i = 0; i < ifmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++) {
        // Just video
        if (i != videoStreamIndex)
            continue;
        avcodec_free_context(&stream_ctx[i].dec_ctx);
        if (ofmt_ctx && ofmt_ctx->nb_streams > i && ofmt_ctx->streams[i] && stream_ctx[i].enc_ctx)
            avcodec_free_context(&stream_ctx[i].enc_ctx);
        if (filter_ctx && filter_ctx[i].filter_graph)
            avfilter_graph_free(&filter_ctx[i].filter_graph);
    }
    av_free(filter_ctx);
    av_free(stream_ctx);
    avformat_close_input(&ifmt_ctx);
    if (ofmt_ctx && !(ofmt_ctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE))
        avio_closep(&ofmt_ctx->pb);
    avformat_free_context(ofmt_ctx);

    /*if (ret < 0)
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Error occurred: %s\n", av_err2str(ret));*/

    return ret ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: The answer is the the error message. The input picture width is greater than stride. Set the stride correctly.

Comment: @szatmary the only thing  stride on the frame seems to be qstride and the documentation says 
`int  qstride
  QP store stride
encoding: unused
decoding: Set by libavcodec.`
Also it's interesting that upscaling works without error ... but crops the image to the original size after scaling.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thanks for the notes ! Are you familiar with ffmpeg ?

Comment: @Vali _"Are you familiar with ffmpeg ?"_ Roughly, yes. Mostly used the command line tools.

Comment: The stride values are parameters passed into sw_scale function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution.

Although calling cmd-line ffmpeg with the exact same filter string just works without added parameters, it seems that in code you need to also set the encoding context options in case of scaling.

In the test code above they would be:

```
enc_ctx->height = dec_ctx->height * scale_value;
enc_ctx->width = dec_ctx->width * scale_value;
```

This seems to fix both the cropping problem when upscaling and the error when downscaling.

Thanks to all for your time debugging this & sorry if my post was in any way unclear (I'm new to this).